# String.contains in Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following query. How can I make it one query with string to be included if its not null or empty

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventRequestModel.Description))
    {
      if (eventRequestModel.Severity.Count > 0)
      {
        eventsModelList = (from job in _unitOfWork.Repository<Jobs>().Get(j => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(j.JobId.ToString())).Result
                           join ev in _unitOfWork.Repository<EventLogs>().Get(e => e.Description.Contains(eventRequestModel.Description) && eventRequestModel.Severity.Contains(e.Severity.ToString())).Result on job.JobId equals ev.JobId
                           join pnl in _unitOfWork.Repository<Panels>().Get(el => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(el.JobId.ToString())).Result on ev.PanelId equals pnl.PanelId
                           orderby ev.TimeStamp descending, ev.EventId descending
                           select new EventsModel
                           {
                             UTCTimeStamp = ev.TimeStamp,
                             EventType = ev.EventType,
                             Description = ev.Description,
                             PanelName = pnl.Name,
                             SiteName = job.Name,
                             ChannelGuid = ev.ChannelGuid,
                             MapGuid = ev.MapGuid,
                             Severity = ev.Severity,
                             LogType = ev.LogType,
                             Data1 = ev.Data1,
                             Data2 = ev.Data2,
                             Data3 = ev.Data3,
                             Data4 = ev.Data4,
                             PanelItemType = ev.PanelItemType,
                             PanelItemId = ev.PanelItemId
                           }).Take(numOfItems).ToList();
      }
      else
      {
        eventsModelList = (from job in _unitOfWork.Repository<Jobs>().Get(j => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(j.JobId.ToString())).Result
                           join ev in _unitOfWork.Repository<EventLogs>().Get(e => e.Description.Contains(eventRequestModel.Description)).Result on job.JobId equals ev.JobId
                           join pnl in _unitOfWork.Repository<Panels>().Get(el => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(el.JobId.ToString())).Result on ev.PanelId equals pnl.PanelId
                           orderby ev.TimeStamp descending, ev.EventId descending
                           select new EventsModel
                           {
                             UTCTimeStamp = ev.TimeStamp,
                             EventType = ev.EventType,
                             Description = ev.Description,
                             PanelName = pnl.Name,
                             SiteName = job.Name,
                             ChannelGuid = ev.ChannelGuid,
                             MapGuid = ev.MapGuid,
                             Severity = ev.Severity,
                             LogType = ev.LogType,
                             Data1 = ev.Data1,
                             Data2 = ev.Data2,
                             Data3 = ev.Data3,
                             Data4 = ev.Data4,
                             PanelItemType = ev.PanelItemType,
                             PanelItemId = ev.PanelItemId
                           }).Take(numOfItems).ToList();
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (eventRequestModel.Severity.Count > 0)
      {
        eventsModelList = (from job in _unitOfWork.Repository<Jobs>().Get(j => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(j.JobId.ToString())).Result
                           join ev in _unitOfWork.Repository<EventLogs>().Get(e => eventRequestModel.Severity.Contains(e.Severity.ToString())).Result on job.JobId equals ev.JobId
                           join pnl in _unitOfWork.Repository<Panels>().Get(el => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(el.JobId.ToString())).Result on ev.PanelId equals pnl.PanelId
                           orderby ev.TimeStamp descending, ev.EventId descending
                           select new EventsModel
                           {
                             UTCTimeStamp = ev.TimeStamp,
                             EventType = ev.EventType,
                             Description = ev.Description,
                             PanelName = pnl.Name,
                             SiteName = job.Name,
                             ChannelGuid = ev.ChannelGuid,
                             MapGuid = ev.MapGuid,
                             Severity = ev.Severity,
                             LogType = ev.LogType,
                             Data1 = ev.Data1,
                             Data2 = ev.Data2,
                             Data3 = ev.Data3,
                             Data4 = ev.Data4,
                             PanelItemType = ev.PanelItemType,
                             PanelItemId = ev.PanelItemId
                           }).Take(numOfItems).ToList();
      }
      else
      {
        eventsModelList = (from job in _unitOfWork.Repository<Jobs>().Get(j => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(j.JobId.ToString())).Result
                           join ev in _unitOfWork.Repository<EventLogs>().Get() on job.JobId equals ev.JobId
                           join pnl in _unitOfWork.Repository<Panels>().Get(el => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(el.JobId.ToString())).Result on ev.PanelId equals pnl.PanelId
                           orderby ev.TimeStamp descending, ev.EventId descending
                           select new EventsModel
                           {
                             UTCTimeStamp = ev.TimeStamp,
                             EventType = ev.EventType,
                             Description = ev.Description,
                             PanelName = pnl.Name,
                             SiteName = job.Name,
                             ChannelGuid = ev.ChannelGuid,
                             MapGuid = ev.MapGuid,
                             Severity = ev.Severity,
                             LogType = ev.LogType,
                             Data1 = ev.Data1,
                             Data2 = ev.Data2,
                             Data3 = ev.Data3,
                             Data4 = ev.Data4,
                             PanelItemType = ev.PanelItemType,
                             PanelItemId = ev.PanelItemId
                           }).Take(numOfItems).ToList();
      }
```

Comment: Having removed all the code (although it's still in the history), you've now made this question worthless to the site. If you were asked to remove it because it was sensitive in some way, please replace it with sufficiently similar code that the problem you faced is still obvious - and the solution Prasad provided you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your difference is

```
join ev in _unitOfWork.Repository<EventLogs>().Get(e => e.Description.Contains(eventRequestModel.Description) && eventRequestModel.Severity.Contains(e.Severity.ToString()))

                                                      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Here
```

You can use ternary operator to avoid `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventRequestModel.Description))` check

Like,

```
join ev in _unitOfWork.Repository<EventLogs>()
 .Get(e => 
      string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventRequestModel.Description) ? true : e.Description.Contains(eventRequestModel.Description)
      && eventRequestModel.Severity.Contains(e.Severity.ToString()))
```

Your entire code will look like,

```
if (eventRequestModel.Severity.Count > 0)
      {
        eventsModelList = (from job in _unitOfWork.Repository<Jobs>().Get(j => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(j.JobId.ToString())).Result
                           join ev in _unitOfWork.Repository<EventLogs>().Get(e => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventRequestModel.Description) ? true : e.Description.Contains(eventRequestModel.Description) 
                                                                             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Your answer is here
                           && eventRequestModel.Severity.Contains(e.Severity.ToString())).Result on job.JobId equals ev.JobId
                           join pnl in _unitOfWork.Repository<Panels>().Get(el => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(el.JobId.ToString())).Result on ev.PanelId equals pnl.PanelId
                           orderby ev.TimeStamp descending, ev.EventId descending
                           select new EventsModel
                           {
                             //Your code
                           }).Take(numOfItems).ToList();
      }
      else
      {
        eventsModelList = (from job in _unitOfWork.Repository<Jobs>().Get(j => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(j.JobId.ToString())).Result
                           join ev in _unitOfWork.Repository<EventLogs>().Get(e => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventRequestModel.Description) ? true : e.Description.Contains(eventRequestModel.Description) 
                                                                             // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Your answer is here  
                           && eventRequestModel.Severity.Contains(e.Severity.ToString())).Result on job.JobId equals ev.JobId
                           join pnl in _unitOfWork.Repository<Panels>().Get(el => eventRequestModel.SiteIds.Contains(el.JobId.ToString())).Result on ev.PanelId equals pnl.PanelId
                           orderby ev.TimeStamp descending, ev.EventId descending
                           select new EventsModel
                           {
                             //Your code
                           }).Take(numOfItems).ToList();
      }
    }
```

Comment: how can I reduce it further by removing eventRequestModel.Severity.Count?

Comment: Yeah you can do that I am working on it give me a sec

Comment: @Gauravsa, Use `eventRequestModel.Severity.Count` condition with ternary operator this will create 4 combinations. Do you want me to write that combinations. If yes I will write it for you, but I believe you can do it by your self